# How to know JDK version from within Java code

Tags: version, java

How to know JDK version from within Java code

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I presume you mean just the Java version, in which case try this:

```
String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
```

Answer (score 5):

Since java 9

```
System.out.println(Runtime.version());
```

Prints something like `17.0.2+8-86`

or if you need more

```
System.out.println("Java Feature Version = " + Runtime.version().feature());
System.out.println("Java Interim Version = " + Runtime.version().interim());
System.out.println("Java Update Version = " + Runtime.version().update());
System.out.println("Java Version Build = " + Runtime.version().build().map(String::valueOf).orElse("Unknown"));
System.out.println("Java Version Pre-Release Info = " + Runtime.version().pre().orElse("N/A"));
```

Prints

```
Java Feature Version = 17
Java Interim Version = 0
Java Update Version = 2
Java Version Build = 8
Java Version Pre-Release Info = N/A
```

Answer (score 4):

Relying on the java.version string for anything else than showing to a human is fragile and will break if running on another Java implementation.

The *only* reliable way programatically is to use reflection to carefully ask if a given facility is available, and then select the appropriate code accordingly.

Comment: Can you give an example of when this would fail?

Comment: @Jesse, I'd rather put it the other way around.  What rule would you set up for analyzing the java.version string?

Comment: Well, I would use java.specification.version instead of java.version, and the code would look like: If( Float.valueOf( System.getProperty("java.specification.version")) ≥= 1.6 ) {doJava6Thing}; else { doJava5Thing }

Comment: @Jesse, I was unaware of this property.  I can, however, not see from a quick look in the JLS that it is guaranteed to be present and containing a valid number.  Perhaps you know where it says so?

Comment: @Jesse, also please note that by using _another_ property you agree with that it is not java.version that is the property to be analyzed.

Comment: Yes, you're correct that java.version is not the best way to determine the JDK version. The java.specification.version is documented here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/versioning/spec/versioning2.html

Comment: @Jesse, the crucial question here if this is for Hotspot-based JVM's only.  I cannot immediately tell.

Comment: Don't use `Float.valueOf` like @JesseBarnum. This failed for me because `1.8>=1.8` returned false for me, due to round-off errors. Use `.compareTo("1.8")>=0` instead.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus, I think your way would work, but I'd feel safer with this check: new BigDecimal( specVersion ).compareTo( new BigDecimal( "1.8" ) ) >= 0;

Comment: I recommend against `.compareTo("1.8") >= 0` because it will fail if there's a version `11.8` or `10.1.8`. If you're going to use strings, you need to use something like `startsWith` or a regular expression.

Comment: As of Java 9, the java.specification.version has moved to be a single integer.

Comment: sometimes one need version just to show in stdout or in logs - and nowhere logic relies on it's value

Comment: @shabunc Then you are not "Relying on the java.version string for anything else than showing to a human".

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the bit version(32bit or 64 bit) as well, and you are running a hotSpot JVM, you can try this code:

`System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")`

No grantee that it will work for other Java implementaions rather than hotSpot.