# Java: How to check jdk version?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know JDK version from within Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638994/how-to-know-jdk-version-from-within-java-code)

In my java code I want to check `jdk` version. If it is 1.5 or above than & than only I want to go ahead with further execution. How to get the `jdk` version ?

Comment: see [this][1]

    System.getProperty("java.version")


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103121/how-to-find-the-jvm-version-from-a-java-program

Comment: System.getProperty("java.version");

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this condition

```
Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("java.version").split("\\.")[1]) >= 5
```

to check the Java version.

Answer (score 4):

```
String version = System.getProperty("java.specification.version");
```

That will give you the string `1.5` for example. Easy to parse.

Answer (score 3):

```
String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
```